# Visual Studio can't find toPromise

Tags: visual-studio, angular, asp.net-core

i used Visual Studio for a WebApp-Projekt with Angular2 as frontend and asp.core as backend.

Now i want to get a status from my API. The Api works, i used it first with postman.

In my Angular-Component, the component says it does not know about toPromise(). i think the code works, but visual studio blocked to build the app.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ImportState } from './importstate';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


@Injectable()
export class ImportService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'user': 'Superadmin', 'password':'Rest!12345' });
    private heroesUrl = 'api/import/';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getStatus(type : string): Promise<ImportState> {
        return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl + 'getStatus/' + type, { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() as ImportState)
            .then(r => console.log(r))
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        //console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }


}
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: It's most probably an issue with the RxJS import operator.
Check that out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941329/why-am-i-getting-a-error-loading-rxjs-extensions-in-angular-2

Comment: Install latest TypeScript for Visual Studio 2015 from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593